# Tool for manage incidents CIO / IT

Tags: productivity

I don't know if I have an answer here, but we have just set up an CIO. Currently, we had a WP to manage, but it is difficult to follow up. Response time. Service with the most demand. Do you know of any practical tools for managing incidents?

Comment: CIO = Chief Information Officer? WP = WordPress?

Comment: Yes that’s correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Then there a lot of tools out there to manage incidents. What you are looking for is a ticketing software.

Self-Hosted Free/Open Source:

- SpiceWorks (I believe on of the most famous on the market)
- OpenSupports
- OsTicket

Self-Hosted Paid:

- Quest KACE (formerly DELL)
- Cherwell

Cloud Hosted (Paid):

- FreshDesk
- ZenDesk

Please note that the list above is not even remotely exhaustive as there are hundreds if not thousands of ticketing software that will allow you to do incident management.

What I really suggest is to sit down with your team and create a [URS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_requirements_document). Then decide three of the ticketing software that fits the URS, demo them and go from there.

Comment: I suppose there is a lot of tools, but I wanted to know which was the most used. Thank you for your list and your suggestion.

Comment: The most used might not fit your needs or workflows. You will need to invest some time to find the most suitable for your use case. In the company I work for we have been researching for the most suitable one for our use case for months and months and we still haven't concluded in a single software.